# Cant export a large data frame to xlsx in R

Tags: r, dataframe, xlsx

Getting an error when I export a 27k row, 200 column data.frame to an xlsx.

```
Error in .jcheck(silent = FALSE) : 
  Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>.jcall(row[[ir]],  
  "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;", "createCell", as.integer(colIndex[ic] - 1))
  <S4 object of class "jobjRef">
```

I have no idea how to fix this error.. any help?

EDIT

I cleared a ton of memory and got this error now

```
Error in .jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook") : 
  Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>.jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook")<S4 object of class "jobjRef">
```

Comment: Don't use the excel stuff in R myself, it's really calling out to some java code. Why not just CSV it out and import it in excel via that route? I suspect from my experience that you would find that quite robust.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's always good to share a portion of the code you used before getting the error, as well as some data that can make it reproducible (that may not be possible with your actual data, but you might be able to reproduce the behaviour with random-generated data)

Comment: Agree with @ShawnMehan comment on better using csv, if possible.

Comment: In addition to the csv option, you could try **XLConnect** or **openxlsx**. I have in the past had better luck writing large objects to xls files rather than xlsx when using **xlsx** or **XLConnect**.

Comment: openxlsx worked great thanks